# simplify method call with return value

Tags: java, methods, return

Is there a simpler way to do

```
foo = method(foo);
```

assuming `method` returns whatever type `foo` is.

I am just curious as it would really save a lot of typing.

Answer (score 0):

If the `foo` object is mutable than you do not need to get back. It will be updated automatically. Because the reference is being updated. But if it's immutable than you have to return it and hold back in `foo` object.